# Explicit model binding in resource routes?

Tags: php, rest, laravel, routes, laravel-5.1

Consider `Route::resource('foo/bar', 'MyController');`. Laravel will look for a model named `Bar` for all REST routes (e.g. for `foo/bar/2` it looks for a `Foo` model with `id=2`). However, I need to map that resource to another model (e..g `Baz` model). How to do that?

Comment: did you add route model bindings?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Illuminate\Routing\Router` 's `bind` method. In your `RouteServiceProvider` class add this to the `boot` method:

**Note:** I'm just assuming that the route key name is `bar` since that's what Laravel will likely use by default (based on your route definition).

### Update

If different URI binds different model, you can create conditional statement like so:

```
$router->bind('bar', function($value) {
    // Following REST
    // @index
    if (Request::isMethod('get') && Request::is('foo/bar')) {
        return Bar::where('id', $value)->first();

    // @edit
    } elseif (Request::isMethod('get') && Request::is('foo/bar/*/edit')) {
        // return other model

    // @show
    } elseif (Request::isMethod('get') && Request::is('foo/bar/*')) {
        // return other model

    // @update
    } elseif (Request::isMethod('put') && Request::is('foo/bar/*')) {
        // return other model
    }
});
```

Not the cleanest solution, but you get the point. Don't forget to import the related namespaces.

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that `bar` in different paths may refer do different models.